# Error when trying to access the site pages link in a sharepoint site 2010

Tags: error, sharepoint-enterprise

Hi i am getting an error while trying to access the

```
http://sitecol/sitename/SitePages/default.aspx
```

> Error --> This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (2000 items) enforced by the administrator. 
>   To view items, try selecting another view or creating a new view. If you do not have sufficient permissions to create views for this list, ask your administrator to modify the view so that it conforms to the list view threshold.
>   Learn about creating views for large lists.

Update --> Error Log :

> Error while executing web part: System.StackOverflowException: Operation caused a stack overflow.
>    at Microsoft.Xslt.NativeMethod.CheckForSufficientStack()
>    at (XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator , Double , XPathNavigator , XPathNavigator , XPathNavigator , XPathNavigator )
>    at (XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator , Double )
>    at (XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator , String )
>    at (XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator , String )
>    at (XmlQueryRuntime )
>    at Root(XmlQueryRuntime )
>    at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer, Boolean closeWriter)
>    at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(IXPathNavigable contextDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter results)
>    at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, XmlWriter results)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.ExecuteTransform(XslCompiledTransform xslCompiledTransform, XsltArgumentList xmlArguments, Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform)

Comment: Are there actually more than 2000 pages in that list\doclib?

Comment: i do not think that there are more than 2000 pages,actually this is the first time that i browse that link..i found out that it is throwing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on 'View all site content' and look for that library.  The number of items in that list will be listed to the right.  If there are more than 2000 items then you will need someone to create a view that results in less than 2000 items using either folders or paging and then link to that view instead.

If the 2000 item limit is too restrictive then you will need to convince your admin (and likely a governance board) to [lift that restriction](http://sharepointnomad.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/solving-the-attempted-operation-is-prohibited-because-it-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold-error/).

Comment: You can also open the page in designer and find out which list thats being added and follow Dave's steps above to resolve the issue.